# Thread synchronisation for very short tasks

Tags: multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

I have a C++ application running on winapi. Portability is not an issue. All I want is maximum performance. I have a basic understanding of multithreading and synchronization issues, but limited experience with the multitude of options ranging from winapi over C++ threads to third party libraries.

In the performance critical core of my application I identified a loop, which could be parallelized. I managed to split the loop into 4 parts which do not depend on each other. I would like to delegate the job to 4 threads running in parallel. The main thread should wait until all 4 threads have done their job, before it continues.

Sounds very simple. However, currently the loop takes only about 10 microseconds when running on one thread. I'm afraid that synchronization methods which cause a switch to the kernel (events, mutexes, etc.) would produce more overhead than the parallelization could save. SRWLocks + condition variables claim to be very lightweight, but I didn't find a way to solve my synchronization with these tools.

Of course I could test all kinds of synchronization APIs, but I'm sure this has been done before.

So my question is: Is there a reasonable way to synchronize very short tasks and if so, what are the appropriate tools?

Comment: If you simply need to fire the threads then wait for them to complete just do a WaitForMultipleObjects on the thread handles.The question of whether actually splitting your task into multiple threads is one that can only be answered by putting together an implementation and timing both the single and multi-threaded approaches.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir That's extremely heavy for such a light application requiring creating the threads and waiting for them to be cleaned up. The cost of doing that will swamp any conceivable benefit.

Comment: Creating and destroying four threads just to have them each run for a few microseconds doesn't make any sense. If you're only doing this task once, speeding it up is pointless. (If you're going to be doing it a lot, creating and destroying threads each time is the worst possible approach.)

Comment: If you have to do this task more than once, you're way better off having a single thread do the whole task and do the task multiple times in parallel. Even the cost of "conveying" the work and results between threads may swamp any benefit. Is this super latency sensitive? Can you explain more about how this is a performance bottleneck for your application?

Comment: "*If you're going to be doing it a lot, creating and destroying threads each time is the worst possible approach*" - that is where thread pools can come into play...

Comment: C++20 coroutines (available since Visual Studio 2015 Update 1) manage the thread pool transparently for you. Waiting for an arbitrary number of coroutines is [almost trivial](https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/62c420a6d977b60488338e9a8376c4d9).

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. They helped me to sort out inappropriate ways and opened my eyes for new options. I will make some experiments and may be come back with more precise questions.

Comment: @David Schwartz: It is clear that creating and destroying  threads for microseconds doesn't make sense. I'm thinking of four (the number four is just a placeholder for # of hardware threads, on a 16 core machine I would use 16 threads) threads running permanently.

Comment: @David Schwartz: My app is a simulation updating a complex net of objects. Currently the net consists of a few hundred knots, which is absolutely no problem. But I want to increase the number of knots as far as possible and it is foreseeable that I will run into performance problems sooner or later.

Comment: The update algorithm consists of two steps. Each of these steps can be applied to the knots in arbitrary order, but step 1 must be completed before step 2 can start. I can portion the whole net into four (or more) parts and delegate each part to a separate thread. My problem is: Each thread has to pause after step 1 and wait until all threads have finished their job. Then each thread makes step 2, wait for completion of the other threads and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to wait for threads to complete you would use WaitForMultipleObjects on the thread handles. The other direct option would be to use a synchronization barrier, a primitive that allows a group of threads to halt until all members of the group have reached the barrier, but that is generally for the case where there is more work for the spawned threads to perform after being released.

Your question of whether this would actually be of benefit in your particular case is one that can only be answered through implementation and timing. And note that if you are going to perform this testing it should be done on a release build with optimizations enabled. It may well be the case that if the amount of work to perform is short enough that the time involved in thread management dwarfs any benefit.

Comment: It seems that synchronization barrier is exactly what I need. I will test it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> The update algorithm consists of two steps. Each of these steps can be applied to the knots in arbitrary order, but step 1 must be completed before step 2 can start. I can portion the whole net into four (or more) parts and delegate each part to a separate thread. My problem is: Each thread has to pause after step 1 and wait until all threads have finished their job. Then each thread makes step 2, wait for completion of the other threads and so on.

You want to break the work into a large number of small chunks and have a fixed pool of threads take chunks of work. Do not make 8 threads on an 8 core machine and split the work into 8 chunks. That algorithm will work poorly if, for one reason or another, only 7 of those cores winds up doing work for you. Your algorithm will need twice as long as the second half of the time only one core is working.

The easy way is to have an extra dispatch thread. Just keep a "work unit" count somewhere protected by a mutex. When a thread finishes a work unit, have it decrement the "work unit" count. When it hits zero, broadcast a condition variable. That will wake the dispatch thread which will then do whatever it takes to get the worker threads going again. It can start them by setting the "work unit" count to the right level and broadcasting another condition variable that the worker threads wait for.

You can also just keep a count of which node needs to be done next and the number of nodes currently doing work. That will require synchronization after each thread though (to figure out which node to do next) and it may make more sense to have each thread grab some number of nodes, iterate over them, and then synchronize to grab another few nodes.

Avoid breaking the work into large chunks early. That can lead to the problem where you have 8 cores but 2 large work units left at some point. Remember, many modern CPUs run their cores at different speeds based on temperature and power measurements.